# python Tkinter cannot reference __init__

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two classes in their own file. 
First class is called class Stock and the other one is the Tkinter GUI class.The problem is that it says tk.Stock(name) cannot find reference `__init__` from class Stock.

What I am trying to do is that use the user's input from the symbol entry to create new instance of class each time when the user input a new entry.

It doesn't have to be this one using a dictionary but I just ran across some tips on how to do this with dictionary but i'm stuck on the classes.

My stock class file:

```
class Stock(object):
    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first = first
```

My Gui class file:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.controller = controller
       self.symbol = StringVar(self)
       self.entry_symbol = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.symbol)
       self.pack()

       self.symbols = {}
       name = self.symbol.get()
       self.symbols[name] = Stock(name)
```

Comment: `Stock` is not a part of `tk` module, is it? The reference to `tk.Stock(name)` is probably invalid.

Comment: No it's not. How do I make this work? I did self.Stock but it didn't work as well.

Comment: It is simply `Stock`.

Comment: okay I did that but not it says unexpected argument 'name' ....that's the part where it's confusing me..

Comment: Please update your code in the example.

Comment: oh sorry okay just did it...

Comment: I run your code in python3, and it runs without errors.

Comment: What python do you use: 2 or 3?

Comment: oh my god... thank you DYZ there isn't an error anymore. I messed up big time! i mis-spelled __init__ with __int__